# Facebook and G+ login with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview

My iOS app has a login page that is set up in a `UIWebView`. It also has a Facebook and G+ login. I can get the normal login screen to work, alright. But I am having problems when I do that with Facebook and G+. I am assuming that the reason is the New Window that pops up with the button click.
Is there any way that I can handle this without resorting to Manual Login?

Comment: can you please elaborate more .. I don't understand what are you trying to do

Comment: @EICaptain There is a "Login" button, that I have implemented natively.It connects to a UIWebView. The UIWebView loads a webpage that has 2 Buttons- "Facebook Login and Google+ Login". It is done completely in the web. But the UIWebView doesn't respond correctly to those clicks. ie, it does not get logged via Facebook or Google+

Comment: Does the login page work when you open it with iOS Safari browser?

Comment: @SidharthJDev as Jehna1 mentioned, is that working when you open in Safari? If that works, then you need to check on AppDelegate if an URL is being opened on `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

Comment: Yes, it does work in safari

Comment: @SidharthJDev you got to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to use native Facebook and G+ login. What you are trying to accomplish is much more complex than using native logins.

If you really, for some reason, must do it in a UIWebView, you would have to implement some strategy like this:

- override `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method of `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.
- in your implementation, you should open the login interface in another modal UIWebView and handle login events there, and on the dismissal of that modal view, if login was successful continue with the app flow.

That would look something like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    //for facebook login
    if ([[url absoluteString] containsString:@"m.facebook.com"] && [[url absoluteString] containsString:@"login"]) {

        // instantiate and present new modal UIViewController containing UIWebView that loads the url. 
        return NO;
    }

    //for G+ something similar

    return [super webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];

}
```

Then, the modal viewControllers for login would also have to implement the logic of how to handle the possible login events, and dismiss itself on success, which would be very complex.

The first webView would than also have to know when the modal is dismissed (can be done with protocol or some other way), and then check the login status, and proceed if successful.

So, as I said, it would be best if you used the native logins.